# Using Spring-Data-Rest, how to update FK on both sides of OneToOne relationship from one REST call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a Spring-Boot app with

- spring-boot-starter-data-rest
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- h2

I have entities with one-to-one relationship like this:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "party")
    private Party party;

    @Column
    private String street;

    ....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Party {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name  = "address")
    private Address address;

    ...

}
```

And repositories for each entity:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> { }
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PartyRepository extends JpaRepository<Party, Long> { }
```

I create an instance of each entity:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "name": "John Smith" }' \
     http://localhost:8080/parties
```

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "street": "456 main st" }' \
     http://localhost:8080/addresses
```

On the address instance, I create a HATEOAS association to party:

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' \
     -d http://localhost:8080/parties/1 \
     http://localhost:8080/addresses/1/party
```

When I check the associations of address:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/addresses/1/party -i
```

I see the correct party:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
{
  "key" : 1,
  "name" : "John Smith",
  ....
}
```

But, when I check the associations of address:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/parties/1/address -i
```

It does not exist:

```
HTTP/1.1 404
```

**How do I create both associations from a single call using Spring-Data-Rest?**

Comment: can you show us java code where you are saving in party

Comment: It's there above, the save is proxied by JpaRepository and exposed as a POST.

Comment: It's not there, actually, I want to see where you are calling repository.save, I doubt  address is not populated when you are saving the party,  ideally when you save party address should also be saved

Comment: Other than @SpringBootApplication class with a main method, this is the entire application (minus getter/setter). There is no manual calling of repository.save -- this is proxied to REST endpoints automatically by spring-data-rest.

Comment: ok, just realized you are using **@RepositoryRestResource**, thought that you are using **@Repository**

Comment: posted the answer, works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this using [@PrePersist](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) and [@PreUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) on my `Party` class:

```
@Entity
public class Party {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name  = "address")
    private Address address;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void updateAddressAssociation() {
        if (address != null)
            address.setParty(this);
    }

}
```

Here is my app flow:

1. Create the address:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "street": "456 main st" }' \
     http://localhost:8080/addresses
```

2. Create the party

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "name": "John Smith" }' \
     http://localhost:8080/parties
```

3. Associate address with party

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H 'Content-Type: text/uri-list' \
     -d http://localhost:8080/parties/1 \
     http://localhost:8080/addresses/1/party
```

4. Confirm party has address association

```
curl http://localhost:8080/parties/1/address
```

5. Confirm address has party association

```
curl http://localhost:8080/addresses/1/party
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute your curl like below

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "name": "John Smith" , "address":{ "street": "456 main st" }}' \
     http://localhost:8080/parties
```

There are some minor changes I did in Entity

```
@Entity
public class Party implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1735292011581348691L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name  = "address")
    private Address address;


}

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7468012139122259209L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "party")
    private Party party;

    @JsonProperty("street")
    @Column
    private String street;

}
```

Works fine, when I tested. it's saving in both table

curl to get

```
curl -X  http://localhost:8080/parties/1
```

Comment: I don't want to create an association on create. I want to create the entities, then apply an association later on which should apply to FK of both entities. Whether I apply the association to address from party or party from address, I would expect both FK to be updated, but I observed only one update being applied.

Comment: well, I think, you can keep it only one side. Just assume if you have to add data using sql, you will end up  writing two insert and two updates

Comment: I found a solution for this, see my answer

Comment: great just missed thinking of this, though I was using the same for maintaining last updated entities.